# What is a "perceived activity"?

Tags: meaning

I was reading this piece and couldn't find a definition for "perceived activity". I brought a screenshot for some context.

I hope someone can clarify what it means, as I need to translate that part in Albanian.

[image: The Question of Culture, pg. 74]

Comment: They're very much "domain-specific collocations", but to my mind ***social reality*** and ***perceived activity*** both just net down to verbose ways of saying ***things people do***. Maybe with allusions to *what people do in the context of society,* and *what people do that can be **seen** to be done by others* (or perhaps *what they **seem** to be doing*, even if in fact they're not).

Answer (score 2):

A perceived activity is what one appears to be doing. Normally they are doing just what they are seen, or perceived to be doing. The fact that it is called the perceived activity tells you there is another, unseen activity. Perhaps a secret activity going on that is meant to be hidden.